# NullPointer Mocking Kafka Results

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, junit, mockito

I am writing tests and I was looking to mock the result of the kafka admin client, when a topic is created.

I am using Mockito to write my unit tests.

Here is the test code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ListTopicsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaFuture;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import org.mockito.Mock;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.main.Launch;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter;
import io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter;

@QuarkusTest
public class AppTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private App mockApp;

    @Mock
    private Client mockClient;

    @Mock
    private Database mockDatabase;

    @Mock
    private Admin mockKafkaAdmin;

    @Mock
    private ListTopicsResult mockListTopicResult;

    @Mock
    private KafkaFuture<Set<String>> mockKafkaFuture;

    @Mock
    private KafkaFuture<Void> mockKafkaFutureVoid;

    @Mock
    private Set<String> mockSet;

    @Mock
    private CreateTopicsResult mockCreateTopicResult;

    @Mock
    private Map<String, KafkaFuture<Void>> mockKafkaTopicResult;
    
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setupAll() {
        RestAssured.filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter());
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    @Launch(value = {}, exitCode = 1)
    public void testLaunchCommandFailed() {}

    @Test
    public void testCreateTopic() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Mockito.when(mockClient.getKafka()).thenReturn(mockKafkaAdmin);
        Mockito.when(mockClient.getKafka().createTopics(Mockito.anyList())).thenReturn(mockCreateTopicResult);
        Mockito.when(mockCreateTopicResult.values()).thenReturn(mockKafkaTopicResult);
        Mockito.when(mockKafkaTopicResult.get("meme.transmit.test")).thenReturn(mockKafkaFutureVoid);
        mockApp.createTopic("test");
        Mockito.when(mockClient.getKafka().listTopics()).thenReturn(mockListTopicResult);
        Mockito.when(mockClient.getKafka().listTopics().names()).thenReturn(mockKafkaFuture);
        Mockito.when(mockClient.getKafka().listTopics().names().get()).thenReturn(mockSet);
        Assertions.assertTrue(mockApp.containsTopic("test"));
    }
// ...
}
```

I get a nullpointer error when this line is called in the production code:

`Mockito.when(mockCreateTopicResult.values()).thenReturn(mockKafkaTopicResult);`

But as you can see I mocked it with `mockKafkaTopicResult`. What might I be missing here? Also is there an easier method to work with `KafkaAdminClient` when writing unit tests?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, [do not mock classes you don't own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own). You test is not testing anything. It's just coupling the implementation to your test for no gain.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mockito.when(mockClient.getKafka().createTopics(Mockito.anyList()))
       .thenReturn(mockCreateTopicResult);
```

The issue was that I was using `anyList()`, when the `createTopics()` only accepts `Collections`.

The fix: `Mockito.anyCollections()`